# trying to add a default recipient to "Email This Page" extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use the "Email This Page" example at http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html as a base and make my own first Chrome Extension.

What I want to do is simple enough: I want to add a default email address for the recipient.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to find a description of the Chrome Email API.

Anyway, my attempts to add another JSON object/parameter to the additionalInfo variable have included several variations on:

```
    var additionalInfo = {
      "title": document.title,
      "selection": window.getSelection().toString(),

      "mailto": 'foo@foobar.com' // my code

    };

    chrome.extension.connect().postMessage(additionalInfo);
```

I have also tried playing around in the "options.html" file trying to find a 'mailto' call to edit, but again no luck.

I'm beginning to wonder if the API used isn't an external one - perhaps I'm looking in the wrong places for the answer.

anyway - help would be nice.
b

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify the background page:

```
function executeMailto(tab_id, subject, body, selection, mailto) {
    var default_handler = customMailtoUrl().length == 0;
    var action_url = "mailto:" + mailto + "?";
    ...
}
...
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    ...
    executeMailto(tab.id, info.title, tab.url, info.selection, info.mailto);
    ...
});
```

Comment: thanks - I'll try it. where can I find this - and other - type of info on how to work with the Chrome API? I looked thru Google's pages but didn't find this info.